# Install UWP app returns unauthorized error

Tags: uwp, windows-installer, unauthorized

I am getting the following error when i try to install the app through the provided installer when i publish the UWP app. The machine doesn't have powershell or admin access. are those required to install the app through the auto generated installer? Sideloading is enabled.

```
App installation failed with error message: Appinstaller operation failed with error code 0x80190191. Detail: Unauthorized
```

Comment: Hello, when installing UWP apps through the app package, you need to enable developer mode (`Settings` -> `Update and Security` -> `Developer Options`). At the same time, you also need to pay attention to the minimum system version that the system should meet the requirements of the current application package. You can troubleshoot the problem based on [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/troubleshoot-appinstaller-issues)

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT, thanks for the documentation, i checked it before but it doesn't answer if i need admin access and powerhsell or not. Sideloading is enabled and version is higher than the minimum required

Comment: Hello, the developer mode is currently required to install the sideload package, and you need to have administrator access to enable the developer mode. So you can try to install the side load package with the administrator account in the developer mode.